# Select rows, who not have another row with value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with this example data:

[image]

How can I select only blue lines?
 
I don't need green lines, because MSISDN 998973309817 have a row with value in IDENT_NUMBER column...

P.S. Result doesn't matter with or without duplicates

Comment: One way is to use `exists`

Comment: Will the desired rows ***always*** have `NULL` in `IDENT_NUMBER`?  Do you need the results to include `id` and `IDENT_NUMBER`?

Comment: What about the last row?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Thanks, I'll try  
@MatBailie, yes, will the desired rows **always** have `NULL`, `id` need the result.  
@GordonLinoff, please clarify

Comment: @GordonLinoff that id is similar but actually unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that the last row is not selected, I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id <= (select max(t2.id)
               from t
               where t2.msisdn = t.msisdn and t2.ident_number is not null
              );
```

This will select rows only up to the last row with a valid `ident_number`.  If there is no row with a valid `ident_number`, then the subquery returns `NULL`, so the outer comparison fails (for that `msisdn`).

EDIT:

The above returns the *green* lines.  The blue lines would be:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id > coalesce( (select max(t2.id)
                         from t
                         where t2.msisdn = t.msisdn and t2.ident_number is not null
                         ), 0)
```

Comment: Your query returned the opposite result from the desired, but this is also useful in the work. Thank.

Comment: @Nail . . . Sorry about that.  I confused blue and green.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
SELECT * from mytable where MSISDN not in
(
SELECT MSISDN from mytable where IDENT_NUMBER is not null
)
```

`Note` : do not forget to replace "mytable" with your DB table name

Comment: Query is work fine on test database, i try it on operating database. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

This will return all `MSISDN` where the is only one row with that MSISDN.

```
SELECT
  MIN(id)            AS id,
  MSISDN             AS MSISDN,
  MIN(IDENT_NUMBER)  AS IDENT_NUMBER
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  MSISDN
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 1
```

This will return all `MSISDN` that only have `NULL` in `IDENT_NUMBER`.

```
SELECT
  MSISDN
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  MSISDN
HAVING
  MAX(IDENT_NUMBER) IS NULL
```

Each of these only parses the table once and so are generally faster than any answers that use `IN()`, `EXISTS()` or `JOIN`.

Comment: All variants is work fine on test database, i try it on operating database. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Rakesh's answer would work but here is another approach.

You select all rows in `DataTable` and then do

```
DataTable dataTable = Select....
DataTable finalDT = dataTable.Clone();

foreach(DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
{
    bool exist = finalDT.AsEnumerable().Any(row => msisdn == row.Field<String>("MSISDN"));
    if(!exist)
    {
        finalDt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

*I was writing this from head and code is not tested so it may have some mistake. If there is any write it down.

Comment: I don't see php tagged.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, MSISDN, IDENT_NUMBER FROM table_name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $key = $row['MSISDN'];
       if(!is_null($row['IDENT_NUMBER'])) {
         $green[$key] = $row['IDENT_NUMBER'];
         if(array_key_exits($blue, $key)) { unset($blue[$key]); }
       } else {
         if(!array_key_exits($green, $key)) {
           $blue[$key] = $row['IDENT_NUMBER '];
         }
       }
    }
}
```

1. Try to use two arrays to store the info
2. Select info from DB
3. Separate info by IDENT_NUMBER
4. No duplication.

Comment: Don't you like SQL?